# What is the purpose of storing timestamps in the .emacs.desktop file?

Tags: desktop

With activated option `Save State between Sessions` from `Emacs Menu -> Options` Emacs saves its configuration in an .emacs.desktop file. Below comparison of the differences of the original file compared to same file after restart of Emacs:

```
original   : (setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (25636 14209 358494 694000) ...
4x restart : (setq desktop-saved-frameset [frameset 1 (25636 14385 957164 975000) ...
      read-only version number of the used format --^    ^     ^     ^      ^
      read-only timestamp : output of (current-time)  __/   __/   __/    __/

                                                         
original   : '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 14192 867490 100000) ...
4x restart : '((tab-width . 8) (indent-tabs-mode) (buffer-display-time 25636 14346 531244 500000) ...
                                                                         ^     ^     ^      ^
                     read-only timestamp : output of (current-time)   __/   __/   __/    __/

original   : '((buffer-display-time 25636 9431 629799 925000) ...
4x restart : '((buffer-display-time 25636 9549 566579 798000) ...
```

As you can see, the files differ because of different timestamps. This raises the question:

**What is the purpose of storing timestamps in the .emacs.desktop file?**

Comment: `desktop` itself doesn't care (except to avoid them when autosaving I think). They seem to be part of what the `frameset` class  brings in  (do `C-h v frameset`). Why framesets have a timestamp, I have no clue. BTW, the doc string for `frameset` says: ` - frameset-restore takes a frameset, and restores the frames and windows
   it describes, as faithfully as possible`. Note the disclaimer: it may not be *possible* to get everything right. But as I said: I'm waving my arms as fast as I can here - I don't know enough about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark the question as answered after two weeks with no response the only possible conclusion an answer which might be wrong:

*What is the purpose of storing timestamps in the .emacs.desktop file?*

**The timestamps seem not to have any special purpose except of being just there stamping a time spec. on statements.**